# algorithm/software which facilitates: cost function + tasks -> schedule

Tags: python, scheduling, algorithms

I am looking for any software/algorithm(s) capable of taking a cost function (an equation which evaluates how good the placement of a task is) and a list of tasks. The tasks I want to schedule are for a single human to perform, and the timescale is days/weeks.

If this doesn't exist, are there any python modules which would assist me in constructing one?